# How do I get the event parameters and show them as the value of the HTML input box?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, event-handling

**problem**

When I choose a row number in the Select box,
I want to put the value of the input text box of HTML.

But my cord doesn't work normally.

When I check with the console window, the error Uncaught eval keeps popping up and it doesn't work.

**This is the code I wrote.**

First, the HTML file with the Row Select Box.
[image]

*export_getRow.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>
     Header row
    <p>  
    <select name="rowNum" id="rowNum"onchange="google.script.run.setValue()"
                  style="width:280px;height:30px;">
        <option value="none" selected>Please select a row</option>
        <?!= options ?>
    </select>

    <p>
    Select the row with the field title of the data to export.
    <p>

    <button onclick='prevPage()'>prev</button>
    <button onclick='nextPage()'>next</button>
    <button onclick='insertData()'>insert Data</button>

    <script>
      var headerRow = document.getElementById("rowNum");
      headerRow.onchange = function(){
      console.log(headerRow.value);
      console.log(localStorage.setItem("selectRowNum",headerRow.value));}      

      var valueToInsert = localStorage.getItem("selectObjToInsert");  
      console.log(valueToInsert);   

      function prevPage() {
        google.script.run.getSheetListforExport();}

      function insertData() {
        google.script.run.salesforceEntryPoint(valueToInsert,headerRow.value);}  

      function nextPage() {
        google.script.run.setValue();}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When selecting Row Number in the Select box,

I want to take the value in the Row from the spreadsheet and put it in the input text box in HTML.

File with input textbox.

*export_MatchingField*
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <? var value= matchingField(headerRowToInsert); ?>
    <? for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++){?>
    <div style="margin-top:5px;">
      <input type="text" id ="textValue" name='textValue' value = <?= value[i] ?>>
    </div>
    <? } ?>

    <button onclick='prevPage()'>Prev</button>

    <script>
      var textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=textValue]');
      var textToWrite;
      for(var i in textBoxes){
        textToWrite = textBoxes[i].value;
      }

      var headerRowToInsert = localStorage.getItem("selectRowNum");  
      console.log(headerRowToInsert); 

      function prevPage() {
      google.script.run.getRowNum();}    
    </script>
 </body>
```

The following is a gs file that matches the fields.

I took the field name from the outside and compared it to the line in the Google

spreadsheet, so that it will be displayed when it matches.

*matchField.gs*

```
function matchingField(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var LastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var LastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
  var runningLog = '<br>Uploaded following:<br><br>';
  //e => Value obtained from row select box
  var [header, ...values] = ss.getRange(e,1,LastRow,LastCol).getValues(); 

  var url = 'example.com';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,getUrlFetchOptions());
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var dataSobjectsField = data.fields;

  var arr = []
  dataSobjectsField.map(l => {
    var sfObjList = l.name;
    arr.push(sfObjList);
    }).join("");


  for(var i=0 ; i<[header,...values][0].length;i++){
    if(arr.includes([header,...values][0][i])){
      return [header,...values][0]
    }else{
      //select fiend name
    }
  }
}
```

The following is a function that takes the value of the mathing field

and runs it as a sidebar in Google Apps script.

*matchField.gs*

```
function setValue(e){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('export_matchField');
  html.value = matchingField(e);
  var h = html.evaluate()
        .setTitle('DG Connector')
        .setWidth(400)
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(h);
}
```

**desired result**
When selecting the value of the header row select box, I would like to take the value

that matches the row number and put it as the value of the input text box.

A situation in which the event parameter is not present, it is executed,

but not when it is present.

I haven't solved it for days.

Also, onchage does not run. What should I do?

Comment: Apparently there are multiple issues. Please focus on one and add a [mcve] for that specific issue.

Comment: In your showing scripts, 2 HTML files are existing like `export_getRow.html` and `export_MatchingField`. In your Google Apps Script, it seems that the HTML file of `export_matchField` is opened. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between those 3 HTML files and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike

Thank you for your reply.
The expert_getRow.html uses the Select box to display the information in the Google spreadsheet
Select headerRow. HeaderRow means the name of the field where the data is to be inserted.

The matchingField() function in gs takes the selected export_getRow.html as an event and determines the location of the headerRow.
And if the field name in headerRow matches the field name outside,
Returns the list of field names.

Comment: @Tanaike expert_matchField.html can be found in
Displays the matched fields in the input box.

Finally, for the setValue() function, simply the matchingField function is used
Function to execute.
Because setValue() receives the mathsingField function as html.value
That's what I wrote.

I added a picture to the existing post.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for your kind answer. As you told me, I will figure out the problems one by one.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, about your 3 HTML files of `export_getRow.html`, `export_MatchingField` and `export_matchField`, each HTML file is not related and all HTML files are independent. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike
Thank you so much for your quick answer.

html file is
export_getRow.html
export_matchField.html
There are two.

matchField.gs is a function of the gs file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you have 2 HTML files and 1 Google Apps Script file. In your question, the HTML file of `export_getRow.html` is related to another HTML file of `export_matchField.html`? Or each HTML is independent? And, how is the HTML of `export_getRow.html` opened?

Comment: @Tanaike The two HTML files are related.
Because the value obtained from export_getRow.html

From export_matchField
<? var value= matchingField(e); ?>

Because I want to import it as an event parameter like this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike. Thank you for trying to solve my problem for a long time.
I don't think I can deliver it properly because I lack English skills.
I'll ask you a question in more detail next time.

Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: By guessing your situation and goal, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? But, I'm not sure whether this modification is your expected result. I apologize for this. So if I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your showing script, at `export_getRow.html`, when the dropdown list is selected, I thought that `headerRow.onchange = function(){,,,}` is run. By this, `google.script.run.setValue()` is not run. So, I thought that this situation is different from your current issue.
- When I removed `headerRow.onchange = function(){,,,}`, when the dropdown list is selected, I think that `google.script.run.setValue()` is run. But, unfortunately, no value is used with `google.script.run.setValue()`. By this, I'm worried that an error occurs at `var [header, ...values] = ss.getRange(e,1,LastRow,LastCol).getValues();`.
- And, at `<? var value= matchingField(headerRowToInsert); ?>`, `headerRowToInsert` is not declared.

I thought that these might be your current issues. When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

Please modify `setValue` as follows.

```js
function setValue(e) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('export_matchField');
  html.inputtags = matchingField(e).reduce((s, f) => s += `<div style="margin-top:5px;"><input type="text" id ="textValue" name='textValue' value='${f}'></div>`, "");
  var h = html.evaluate().setTitle('DG Connector').setWidth(400).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(h);
}
```

- In the current stage, when the loop process is used with the template, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f1436d88423077115d2c249862f12f17) So, I created HTML outside of the template using a loop.

#### HTML side: `export_getRow.html`

Please modify `export_getRow.html` as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Header row
  <p>
    <select name="rowNum" id="rowNum"onchange="google.script.run.setValue(this.selectedIndex + 1)" style="width:280px;height:30px;">
        <option value="none" selected>Please select a row</option>
        <?!= options ?>
    </select>

  <p>
    Select the row with the field title of the data to export.
  <p>

    <button onclick='prevPage()'>prev</button>
    <button onclick='nextPage()'>next</button>
    <button onclick='insertData()'>insert Data</button>

    <script>
      var headerRow = document.getElementById("rowNum");
      // headerRow.onchange = function(){
      //   console.log(headerRow.value);
      //   console.log(localStorage.setItem("selectRowNum",headerRow.value));
      // }      

      var valueToInsert = localStorage.getItem("selectObjToInsert");  
      console.log(valueToInsert);   

      function prevPage() {
        google.script.run.getSheetListforExport();}

      function insertData() {
        google.script.run.salesforceEntryPoint(valueToInsert,headerRow.value);}  

      function nextPage() {
        google.script.run.setValue();}

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### HTML side: `export_matchField.html`

Please modify `export_matchField.html` as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <?!= inputtags ?>

  <button onclick='prevPage()'>Prev</button>

  <script>
    var textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=textValue]');
      var textToWrite;
      for(var i in textBoxes){
        textToWrite = textBoxes[i].value;
      }

      var headerRowToInsert = localStorage.getItem("selectRowNum");  
      console.log(headerRowToInsert); 

      function prevPage() {
      google.script.run.getRowNum();}    
  </script>
</body>
```

#### Note:

- By above modification, I think that after the HTML of `export_getRow.html` was oprned, and when the dropdown list is selected, `google.script.run.setValue(this.selectedIndex + 1)` is run, and `export_matchField.html` is opened by including the input tags created by the value from `matchingField(e)`.
- In this answer, it supposes that your function of `matchingField(e)` works fine and your expected value is returned by giving `e`, and also, first, your `export_getRow.html` can be correctly opened. Please be careful about this.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you for your detailed answer.

I applied the code as you told me, but I checked it with the console and found the following error.
Uncaught at setValue (Salesforce:659)

And the 659 line is as follows.
html.inputtags = matchingField(e).reduce((s, f) => s += `<div style="margin-top:5px;"><input type="text" id ="textValue" name='textValue' value='${f}'></div>`, "");

May I know what the problem is?
You've already helped me so much that I can't ask for more help
I'm just sorry.

Comment: @whytili Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. So, can you provide the detail of your current situation for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. Because when I tested my proposed script using my sample value, no error occurs. I think that the reason that no error occurs is due to my poor skill. I really apologize for my poor skill again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
From export_getRow.html
google.script.run.setValue(this.selectedIndex + 1) =>
google.script.run.setValue(this.selectedIndex)

I changed it to and I was able to see the result I wanted!

Thank you for your great help.
But I have another problem.
Can I solve it and ask you a question again if it doesn't work out?

I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: @whytili Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `But I have another problem. Can I solve it and ask you a question again if it doesn't work out?`, I would like to support you. When you have a new question, please post it as a new question. By this, it will help users including me think of a solution.